# Using different template in XSL based on nodes count

Tags: xslt

Lets say I have xml with 'book' nodes

```
<book>
etc
</book>
```

In my xsl file I have:

```
<xsl:template match = "book">
bla bla
</xsl:template>
```

Of course this works like a charm.
Now I want to use one template if I have only one `<book>` node, and another template if I have 10 `<book>` nodes.

This (below) doesn't work (I suppose because I define templates within a 'choose' statement) Did I guess correctly? And how could I use different templates (if this is not the way) with this condition (count of nodes)

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="count(book) = 1">
 template1 defined here
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 template2 defined here
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define separate templates for the two cases, for example

```
<xsl:template match="*[count(book) = 1]/book">
  <!-- this is called when there is only one book -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <!-- this is called in all other cases -->
</xsl:template>
```

In the one-book case, both templates' match patterns could apply to the same node, but in that case the "more specific" template will win (there are [specific rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict) governing the order of precedence but basically a match that is just an element name will always be overruled by a match that includes a `/` or a predicate in square brackets).

Comment: This is it. Thank you! Too bad I don't have reputation yet to vote your answer up.

Comment: np, I did for you, for an accepted satisfied answer. More ppl would do, as they view it

Answer (score 2):

Templates need to be direct children of the root `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform`. But of course you can write conditions in match patters e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="books[count(book) = 10]/book">...</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="books[count(book) = 1]/book">...</xsl:template>
```